# y = 1/x, range of inverse

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

consider the function y = g(x) and its inverse $x = g^{-1}(y) = h(y)$.  for example:

$$y = g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$$

The range of this function is:

$$-\infty < x < 0,~~~ 0<x<\infty$$

with a discontinuity at zero.

now i consider the inverse

$$y = \frac{1}{x}$$

$$yx = 1$$

$$x = h(y) = \frac{1}{y}$$

taking inverse of range of g(x):

$$-\infty < x < 0,~~~ 0<x<\infty$$

substituting $x = \frac{1}{y}$ into inequalities:

$$-\infty < \frac{1}{y} < 0,~~~ 0< \frac{1}{y}<\infty$$

reciprocating inequalities:

$$\frac{1}{-\infty} < y < \frac{1}{0},~~~ \frac{1}{0}< y< \frac{1}{\infty}$$

$$0 < y < \infty,~~~ \infty < y< 0$$

Now i'm wondering, why the direction of the second inequality isn't correct...

$$\infty < y< 0$$ ???

---

Could be something like this... but this rule that I made up seems somewhat unsatisfying:

3 cases to consider when reciprocating:

- **case 1:** (same sign, flip inequality) $~2 < ~4 \longrightarrow ~0.50 > ~0.25$
- **case 2:** (two signs, flip inequality) $-4 < -2 \longrightarrow -0.25 > -0.05$
- **case 3:** (one sign, don't flip) $-2 < +4 \longrightarrow -0.50 < ~0.25$

Answer (score 2):

Your "reciprocating inequalities" step is invalid for two reasons:

1. As $t$ gets larger, $\frac1t$ gets smaller, so if you take the reciprocal of both sides of an inequality, you need to reverse the inequality. (Example: $2<3$ so $\frac12>\frac13$.) And this only works if both sides have the same sign, so you still have to be careful. (Consider $-2<2$ and $\frac1{-2}=-\frac12<\frac12$.)
2. "$\frac10=\infty$" isn't valid algebra. When people write this, it's shorthand for "as $t$ approaches $0$ from the positive side, $\frac1t$ gets arbitrarily large in the positive direction". Another true statement is "as $t$ approaches $0$ from the *negative* side, $\frac1t$ gets arbitrarily large in the *negative* direction". (We write these as $\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac1t=\infty$ and $\lim_{t\to0^-}\frac1t=-\infty$.) So if you just write $\frac10$, there's not enough information to know whether we should think of this expression as $\infty$ or $-\infty$ (or something else).

To solve your problem, it's better to think intuitively about your function. If $y=\frac1x$ then $x$ can be anything except $0$. If $x$ is positive, then $y$ is positive. If $x$ is negative, then $y$ is negative. As you noticed, we have $x=\frac1y$, so your function is the same as its inverse, so $g=h$ and both have the same domain and range.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}\frac{1}{0} = undefined\end{align}
 We can get the value of it by limits.
\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\ 0^+}\frac{1}{x}=+\infty\\ And, \lim_{x\to\ 0^-}\frac{1}{x}=-\infty\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The purely algebratic way to find range of inverse:

$\text{1/y is negative},~~~\text{1/y is positive}$

$-\infty < \frac{1}{y} < 0,~~~ 0< \frac{1}{y}<\infty$

$-\infty < \frac{1}{y},~~~ \frac{1}{y} < 0,~~~ 0< \frac{1}{y},~~~ \frac{1}{y}<\infty$

$-\infty < \frac{1}{y},~~~ \lim \limits_{z \to 0^-}\bigg(\frac{1}{y} < z\bigg),~~~ \lim \limits_{z \to 0^+}\bigg(z< \frac{1}{y}\bigg),~~~ \frac{1}{y}<\infty$

now reciprocating:

$-\frac{1}{\infty} > y,~~~ \lim \limits_{z \to 0^-}\bigg(y > \frac{1}{z}\bigg),~~~ \lim \limits_{z \to 0^+}\bigg(\frac{1}{z}> y\bigg),~~~ y>\frac{1}{\infty}$

$0 > y,~~~y > -\infty,~~~\infty>y,~~~ y>0$

$0 > y > -\infty,~~~\infty>y>0$

$\boxed{-\infty < y <0,~~~0<y<\infty}$

**Rules for Reciprocating inequalities**

- If $a$ and $b$ have the same nonzero sign, then
  $$a<b \iff \frac1a > \frac 1b$$
  (i.e., taking reciprocals flips the inequality).
- If $a$ and $b$ have opposite (nonzero) signs, then
  $$a<b\iff \frac1a <\frac1b$$

  (i.e., taking reciprocals preserves the inequality).
- given $(a<b)$, If either of $a$ or $b$ is zero, then you can't take reciprocal.  However, you can reciprocate limits that approach zero.
- compound inequalities like $a<b<c$ should be separated into "$a<b$ and $b<c$" and each component considered separately.

---

simplifying the algebra syntax:

$-\infty < x < 0,~~~0<x<\infty$

$-\infty < 1/y < 0^{-},~~~ 0^{+} < 1/y < \infty$

$-1/\infty > y > 1/0^{-},~~~1/0^{+} > y > 1/\infty$

$0 > y > -\infty, ~~~ \infty > y > 0$

$\boxed{-\infty < y <0,~~~0<y<\infty}$